# Bootstrap 3 panel footer with 1 element pulled left and 2 elements pulled right, all on same footer row - how?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, right-align

There are so many questions on this, but they all seem to just want one item on the left and one on the right, or a button group. All of those are straightforward.

How can I achieve similar to this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/92157#)

but **instead of two buttons in the group on the right, two other elements** - two divs, or two h3 for example?

Whatever I try these 2 elements always end up vertically stacked and not horizontally aligned in the right side of the footer.

**EDIT**

@Harinder88 provided this solution which, as you can see, does do what I asked and so I have accepted as the answer as I think in the vast majority of use cases, this is what most people are trying to achieve.

[image]

However, you can see that if the text is too long for the column, it gets wrapped and now everything is not on a single line. But I accept that is the compromise of having a responsive design. It just so happens that in my actual use case, that last item cannot be allowed to wrap, so I just have to give it a fixed width to solve that. Thanks @Harinder88.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now see this example i aligned 2 items horizontal in left and right with 2 methods u can use any 1 of them

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <p>Left side with col</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <p> Right side with col</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-left">
            <div class="pull-left">Left side with pull</div>
             <div class="pull-right">Right side with pull</div>
           </div>

        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
</div>

<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pull-right for align div right and pull-left for align div on left side .
if you want to do further partition you can use use same things again.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="pull-right"> 
             <button class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
             <button class="btn btn-primary active">OFF</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-left">
             <h4>
              Fotter (you can use anything here button code or link tag , you can remove hr tag and use anything you want )
             </h4>
           </div>

        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but you have just copy and pasted the code in the Bootply that I already linked to and also did not read the fact that I DON'T WANT BUTTONS in the footer. I want text items - one on the left and two on the right all aligned in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out by replacing the button groups and the buttons with spans, then it works fine. Everything aligned on one line, 1 item pulled left and 2 pulled right.

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="panel-title">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="col-xs-12">
                <span class="pull-right"> 
                    <span>Recording - Last updated at x</span>
                    <span class="trail-status">PUBLISHED</span>
                </span>
                <h5>x comments
                </h5>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>        
</div>
```